# Run simultaneous or asynchronous tasks with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, asynchronous, capistrano

I have a few long-running restarts of processes in my `deploy.rb` like:

- `rake assets:precompile`
- `script/delayed_job restart`
- `rake sunspot:solr:stop`, `rake sunspot:solr:start`

All of these processes have to occur, but not necessarily one after another.

I was wondering if I can run the `assets:precompile` and the `delayed_job restart` simultaneously, as they don't need to happen one after another, and I could speed up my deploy time by doing them asynchronously.

I've run some Google searches but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: i would love to know it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature that capistrano supports.

I have been looking around for a solution and found something on the [Capistrano google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/capistrano/hZAvU9aHn-A). The suggestion was to use Capistrano to run a ruby script that runs the jobs in parallel using Ruby's own threading support.

If you read the post one of the authors does ask why do these tasks need to run in parallel because you can introduce race conditions and other non-deterministic behaviour which can make the deployment process more brittle.